# Fatal error when calling a crontab

Tags: php, cron, putty

I've just set my crontab php file which is trying to require_once another path.

This is my script crontab which is called crontab.php and it's located in the first folder my hosting allows me (my vissible root):

```
<?php require_once ('/kunden/homepage/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/folder1/folder2/file.inc.php'); ?>
```

Before I've set my path, I've checked with the command pwd to get the full path of my server, that means:

```
(uiserver) :uXXXXX:~ > pwd
/kunden/homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs
```

To make sure it works, I've tried to test it through the command `php cron.php` but unfortunatelly I received this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  main() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/folder1/folder2/test.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in <b>/homepages/31/d466491669/htdocs/cron.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

It's obvious that the problem is on my path but after testing many different possibilities, I can't find the right one.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a typo somewhere? Your `require` talks about `file.inc.php` and the error message is about `test.inc.php`. Also, in your main file, what does `getcwd();` give you?

Comment: about test.inc.php and file. i just changed the names of all my paths anf files so it's correct. about getcwd(), should I do on my cron something like `$execute_path = getcwd() . "/execute.php";` or you mean in the file I want to execute?

Comment: No, just confirm using `getcwd()` that the paths are actually what you think they are.

Comment: The path that after doing it on the cron.php is: `/homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs`

Comment: I already solved the issue by adding 2 lanes: `$base = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));` and `require_once ($base . '/htdocs/folder1/folder2/file.php');` But thanks a lot for your help!